# WPF Application_Startup windows decision

Tags: wpf, startup

I am going to stering my WPF program by external parameter - when the program is call.

In App.xaml.cs I added Startup code and remove StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Create main application window, starting minimized if specified
    //StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    MessageBox.Show(arguments[1]);

    if (arguments[1] == "Window1")
    {
        Window1 mainWindow = new Window1();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    if (arguments[1] == "Window2")
    {
        Window2 mainWindow = new Window2();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

I worried, because this Application_Startup method is not fired.
Can any one want to help me?

Comment: Please post your App.xaml as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access modifier(private void) could be the problem. Instead try the below.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnStartup(e);

  //your code
}
```